# How to print desired pathname

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I want to print the desired output, like `x[0]` should print the first path, and `x[1]` should print the second path. But I don't know how to do it? I used `split` but it didn't give me the expected result.

**Given result**

```
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/
/home/runner/TestP1/folder2/
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/sub
```

**Required result**

```
/home/runner/TestP1/folder2/
```

**Code**

```
import os
 
def filesystem(rootdir):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for subdir in dirs:
          x = os.path.join(rootdir, subdir)
          print(x)

filesystem("/home/runner/TestP1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access each directory as if it were a list, then you need to construct one. Below I have given an example:

```py
import os

all_directories = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"/home/runner/TestP1"):
    all_directories += dirs # Append the list of subdirs in this directory to the master list.

print(all_directories[1])
```

Be mindful that the order will be depth-based. Meaning directories in sub directories will come before adjacent ones. If you want breadth-first ordering, set `top_down` to `False` in `os.walk`.